multiple .bam to .fastq files with samtools
I am trying to convert all .bam files from the directory to .fastq files with samtools.
What I understand with the command
samtools fastq my_bam_file.bam > my_converted_bam_file.fastq

I am able to convert only one file at the time.
How would I convert all the files from the directory one-by-one?
